# Generating same random variable in Rcpp and R

Tags: r, debugging, rcpp, sampling

I am converting my sampling algorithm from R to Rcpp. Output of Rcpp and R are not matching there is some bug in the Rcpp code ( and the difference is not different because of randomization). I am trying to match internal variables of Rcpp with those from R code. However, this is problematic because of randomization due to sampler from distribution.

```
 Rcpp::rbinom(1, 1, 10) 
 rbinom(1, 1, 10)
```

How can I make the code give same output in R and Rcpp, I mean setting a common seed from R and Rcpp?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: See [Rcpp Sugar](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-sugar.pdf); in particular, the section on `RNGScope`.

Answer (score 4):

You are having a number of issues here:

1. `rbinom(1,1,10)` is nonsense, it gets you 'Warning message: In rbinom(1, 1, 10) : NAs produced' (and I joined two lines here for display).
2. So let's assume you wrote `rbinom(10, 1, 0.5)` which would generate 10 draws from a binomial with `p=0.5` of drawing one or zero.
3. Rcpp documentation is very clear about using the same RNGs, with the same seeding, via `RNGScope` objects which you get for free via Rcpp Attributes (see below).

So witness this (with an indentation to fit the first line here)

```
R> cppFunction("NumericVector cpprbinom(int n, double size, double prob) { \
      return(rbinom(n, size, prob)); }")
R> set.seed(42); cpprbinom(10, 1, 0.5)
 [1] 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
R> set.seed(42); rbinom(10,1,0.5)
 [1] 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
R>
```

I define, compile, link and load a custom C++ function `cpprbinom()` here. I then set the seed, and retrieve 10 values.  Resetting the seed and retrieving ten values under the same parameterisation gets the *same* values.

This will hold for all random distributions, unless we introduced a bug which can happen.